# Unable to connect to outlook mailbox using POP3 over proxy server using javamail 1.6.2

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I am trying to connect to an outlook mailbox using POP3 Javamail . This mailbox runs over a proxy server. I tried using Javamail 1.6.2 with the following configuration:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();  
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true"); 
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.starttls.required", "true");

    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.proxy.host", "myproxy.server");
    props.setProperty("mail.pop3.proxy.port", "110");

    props.put("mail.pop3.ssl.trust", "*");
```

I am getting following error in the stacktrace:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: myproxy.server, 110; timeout -1; Using web proxy host, port: myproxy.server, 110 (java.net.ConnectException: connection through proxy myproxy.server:110 to myproxy.server:110 failed: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:217)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:248)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:91)
    at com.zs.prp.services.impl.MailScannerServiceImpl.executeMailScanning(MailScannerServiceImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy328.executeMailScanning(Unknown Source)
    at com.zs.prp.scheduler.MailScannerSchedulerJob.executeInternal(MailScannerSchedulerJob.java:34)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection through proxy ZS-F5LBPOP.zs.local:110 to ZS-F5LBPOP.zs.local:110 failed: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.proxyConnect(SocketFetcher.java:877)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:217)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:118)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.getPort(POP3Store.java:271)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:213)
    ... 20 more
```

Although i am setting `mail.pop3.proxy.server` and `mail.pop3.proxy.host` properties still getting this issue. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the socket factory settings, [you don't need them](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

What kind of proxy server are you using?  The properties you're setting are for a web (http) proxy server.  Web proxy servers are almost certainly not running on the POP3 port 110; you need a different port for the web proxy server; ask your administrator
for the proper port.

You also need to configure the host name for the POP3 server that
you want the proxy server to connect to on your behalf.  Set
the `mail.pop3.host` property.

If none of that help, provide us more details and post the
[JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).